Http Sink Connector - Key isn't substituting correctly
I've set up an HTTP Sink Connector with URL key substitution, but the key isn't substituting correctly. Instead of substituting "14Y0354214", it is being substituted as "%5BB@5a95cb0c".
Stream:
CREATE OR REPLACE STREAM `delete_sync`(`id` VARCHAR KEY, `value` VARCHAR)
WITH (
  KAFKA_TOPIC = 'delete.sync',
  KEY_FORMAT='JSON',
  VALUE_FORMAT='KAFKA'
);


INSERT INTO  `delete_sync`
SELECT 
    CAST(`Member`['id'] AS STRING) AS `id`,
    CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR) AS `value`
FROM 
    `sync_transform`
WHERE 
    `EventType` = 'MemberDeleted'
PARTITION BY CAST(`Member`['id'] AS STRING);

Connector Config:
{
    "connector.class": "HttpSink",
    "header.separator": "|",
    "headers": "apikey:xxxxxxxxxx",
    "http.api.url": "https://domain/api/${key}",
    "input.data.format": "JSON",
    "kafka.auth.mode": "SERVICE_ACCOUNT",
    "kafka.service.account.id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "name": "delete.sync",
    "request.body.format": "json",
    "retry.on.status.codes": "500-",
    "tasks.max": "6",
    "topics": "delete.sync",
    "max.poll.records": "100",
    "behavior.on.null.values": "delete",
    "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
    "key.converter.schemas.enable": "false"

}

Key as to get substitute correctly
